# DynamoDB JSON response parsing prints vertically

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a script that scans a `DynamoDB` table that stores my instance IDs. Then I try to query another table to see if it also has that same instance and get all of the metadata attributes in a master table. When I iterate through the query using the instance ID from the initial scan of the first table, I am noticing each character of the instance id string is being printed to a new line, instead of the entire string on one line. I am confused how to fix this. Below is my code, sample output, and the expected output.

`CODE:`

```
import boto3
import json
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def table_diff():
    dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    table_missing = dynamodb.Table('RunningInstances')

    missing_response = dynamo.scan(TableName='CWPMissingAgent')

    for instances in missing_response['Items']:
        instance_id = instances['missing_instances']['S']
        # This works how I want, prints i-xxxxx
        print(instance_id)

        for id in instance_id:
            # This does not print how I want (vertically)
            print(id)
            query_response = table_missing.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('ID').eq(id))
```

`OUTPUT:`

```
i
-
x
x
x
x
x
```

`EXPECTED OUTPUT:`

```
i-xxxxx
etc etc
```

Answer (score 1):

`instance_id` is a string. Thus, when you loop over it (`for id in instance_id`), you are actually looping over each character in the string, and printing them out individually.

Why do you try to loop over it, when you say that just printing it produces the correct result?

Comment: I loop over it because I need to use those strings in a series of new queries to the master table. I think I need to just make those second queries as part of the first `for` loop and get rid of the second `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, looping over your result (which is a string) makes no sense. If you just want to perform an additional query on each instance_id, just perfom the query. There is no need for an additonal loop.